# Find focal length in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, android-camera

We're building an Obstacle Detection System for visually impared person using mobile camera for college project.

I've made a simple camera app. How to find the focal length of android camera in this app? My
teacher assigned me this task but since i'm not well familiar in flutter. However i made a simple camera app through the help of internet.

I want someone to help me out find the focal length of the android camera. The source code of my camera app is:

```
// import 'dart:io';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<CameraDescription>? cameras;
  CameraController? controller;
  // XFile? image; //for caputred image

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadCamera();
    super.initState();
  }

  loadCamera() async {
    cameras = await availableCameras();
    if (cameras != null) {
      controller = CameraController(cameras![0], ResolutionPreset.max);
      //cameras[0] = first camera, change to 1 to another camera

      controller!.initialize().then((_) {
        if (!mounted) {
          return;
        }
        setState(() {});
      });
    } else {
      print("No any camera found");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("DRISTI"),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF2899bd),
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: Column(children: [
        Container(
            child: controller == null
                ? Center(child: Text("Loading Camera..."))
                : !controller!.value.isInitialized
                    ? Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      )
                    : CameraPreview(controller!)),
      ])),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CameraDescription` class provided by the camera package

Comment: I don't know how this CameraDescription thing work, Can you help me by writing code of focal length in this source code i provided?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).